# How can I get the final dimensions of an object I placed on a page using "pdfmake"?

Tags: pdf, npm, pdf-generation, pdf.js, pdfmake

I want to generate receipts for our sales orders dynamically using `pdfmake` npm package on a `node` backend. Basically, the use case is something like spanning the table rows to the full-page width whenever there are fewer items and breaking the table into two columns whenever there are more items. The tricky part is that not all rows have the same height, so I can't just keep track of how many rows I have added to the table.

[image]

Comment: Everything has to fit on one page. I just need to be able to read the dimensions of the objects/nodes I am planning to put on a page from memory. This way I can try multiple approaches and choose to save the one that I think looks good visually from memory onto the hard disk. Is this even possible with `pdfmake`? Because I wasn't able to find any other versatile free libraries for `node` backend that can handle tables as well.

Comment: That is partly true. I know that an `8.5" x 11"` Letter paper is `612 pt x  792 pt`. Because of the implicit default styles, I can somehow accurately calculate the heights of elements I put on the page to know when I am reaching the bottom of a fillable area on a page. There are 2 issues with this approach: 1. It is not perfectly accurate. 2. It takes extra effort for me to calculate everything that goes into the height. I know for sure that `pdfmake` has to do this internally to be able to generate the PDF, I'm wondering whether they expose their internals to save myself the hassle.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing :( but thanks for the help! I'm not familiar with the underlying `pdfkit` itself as well. But I'll keep an eye out on `pdfmake`'s issues page and see if anything comes up there (I've already created an issue there as well https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/2590)